# One to many relationship join using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have 3 tables collections, collection_images and collection_variations. Collection_images table have all the images for a collection stored in collections table and collection_variations table have all the variations for a collection stored in collections table. The solution i have tried is

```
$this->db->select("collections.*, GROUP_CONCAT(collection_images.image_path) as images", false);
$this->db->from('collections');
$this->db->join('collection_images','collection_images.product_id=collections.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('collections.id');
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

This only gives the all the image_path for a collection as comma seperated value but how to fetch variations and also i want to get all the columns from images and variations table for a collection. The table are below

[collection table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ceayr.png)

[collection_images table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSptl.png)

[collection_variations table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErDmp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add a join for the third table. The query will return a duplicate row from collections for each matching column in variations.

```
$this->db->select("collections.*, GROUP_CONCAT(collection_images.image_path) as images, collection_variations.name as variation" false);
$this->db->from('collections');
$this->db->join('collection_images','collection_images.product_id=collections.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('collection_variations','collection_variations.=collections.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('collections.id');
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```